# Picture book with various information about aliens, including an adventure gamebook style section

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

This was a book I read around 1994-1998. It was in my classroom at primary school, but I believe the teacher had brought it in from home (it was kept on the windowsill with other books belonging to the teacher that we could borrow, rather than in the library with the school's own selection of books). I'm not sure how old the book was at the time; possibly older, definitely not brand new (but it might just have been a bit battered by being borrowed by a lot of eight year olds). I'm not sure if it was actually aimed at children or young adults. It was an outsize picture book, from what I can recall presented in a factual style, about aliens, alien planets and so on; I seem to recall a double page spread showing a suburban house with the roof cutaway, and information around the sides pointing to various things that indicated an alien presence (or something similar; my recollection is hazy!). The part I mostly remember it for was a kind of gamebook section. I think that this was spread throughout the rest of the book, comprising several double page spreads. In the first section you are on board a spaceship which has just crashlanded onto an alien planet, and is quickly sinking (into mud, or quicksand?). You have to select which items from the ship to bring with you to use in later sections, but owing to the time constraints from the sinking can only pick a set number of items. I think the next double page spreads it led you to then had you trying to survive on the alien planet, using the items you had salvaged from the ship; with rescue being the ultimate goal. I think there might have been sections like an encyclopaedia of alien life forms and so on.

It's possible I'm getting my memories conflated with other books; I have read books like Usborne's Puzzle Planet (but this book was definitely aimed at older people than that) which are somewhat similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the book! It turned out to be [Planetfall](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/440786.Planetfall) by Douglas Hill, Tamora Pierce and David Garnett. The section I most remembered was the "Could you survive on an Alien Planet?" portion. From Goodreads:

> **Sentinel of Earth**: Introduces a brand new 'alien' super hero, Rasl Ca'wrn and his sidekick Mizzo. Earth is a target for evil alien villains and only the Sentinel and Mizzo stand in their way in five cliff-hanging episodes...
>
> **Can you survive on an Alien Planet?** This exciting new game challenges you the reader to survive in appallingly hostile conditions after your space capsule has crash-landed on the notorious planet Abthaze....
>
> **Plain Magic**: is a special fantasy feature story about a kind of magic that is quiet but effective, even against the fiercest dragon....
>
> **Aliens and Planets**: can you match the aliens to their planets in this tricky and challenging game?
>
> **Krail's World**: space explorer meets more than he bargained for when he crash-lands on an alien planet in this thought-provoking story.
>
> **Planetfall** is illustrated throughout in full colour and black and white, all the material used is new and it is hoped to follow it down to Earth with Planetfall Two.